# Is there a wall log?

Tags: wall

A tool that runs day and night sometimes posts crucial information to the wall. Is there any way to redirect this output to a file for when I'm asleep? Alternatively, does wall keep a log of messages posted to it or is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Apparently, there are some implementations of `wall` that write to `syslog`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/wall

Comment: And the implementation is here I think: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysvinit/blob/master/src/wall.c

Comment: @Arkadiusz please do add that as an answer.

Comment: @roaima: ok, I did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some implementations of `wall` that write to syslog, for
example http://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysvinit/blob/master/src/wall.c . In
[its
manpage](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysvinit/tree/master/man) it
says:

> For every invocation of wall a notification will be written to syslog,
>   with facility LOG_USER and level BR LOG_INFO

If you cannot control application's behavior or tell it to use `logger`
instead of `wall` you can create a `wall` wrapper that would run a
regular `wall` command and use `logger` to write to `syslog`. You can
either create this wrapper in a new directory, add it to your `$PATH`
and restart program that uses `wall` with new `$PATH` settings or,
especially if you cannot even restart the program, replace system-wide
`wall` for everyone if you have enough permissions to do so. In this
example I will show you how to do the latter. First, rename existing
`wall` program to `wall.orig`:

```
$ command -v wall
/usr/bin/wall
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/wall /usr/bin/wall.orig
```

The new `/usr/bin/wall` wrapper script could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# wall wrapper - run wall commands with specified arguments and write
# a notification to syslog

wall.orig "$@"
logger "wall was ran with the following options: $*, result: $?"
```

Remember to make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/wall
```

Use it like a regular `wall`:

```
$ wall "test message"

Broadcast message from ja@comp (pts/14) (Sat Sep 14 22:34:43 2019):

test message
```

If you have a working `logger` and `syslogd` is running you should see
the following message log in one of the files in `/var/log` that
`syslogd` is routing the messages to:

```
Sep 14 22:34:43 comp ja: wall was ran with the following options: test message, result: 0
```

Of course, keep in mind that each time you will upgrade your system
using its built-in upgrade mechanisms it's possible that the original
`/usr/bin/wall` binary will be restored again.

Comment: Cool stuff! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a logging level that will write to all logged in users with wall

```
logger -p emerg 'The sky is falling in'
```

The logger with write messages to the appropriate file under `/var/log`. For emergency priority messages it will also send them to users with `wall`.

Comment: It doesn't intercept messages posted to the wall though, does it? The tool that I mention, I don't control its behavior -- it always posts to the wall. The idea is to intercept these messages, write them to a file so that when I wake up I can examine it to see if anything happened during the night.